# Python Finding Longest String of Digits Without a Particular Number

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

Sorry if the title is confusing. I am trying to write a python function that takes a string of numbers (digits) as input (ex: "123456789123"). The function should also take in an int n, and then should return the largest segment of the string of digits that does NOT contain n. For example, if my string of numbers was 1211211121 and my n is 2, then my function should return "111" since it is the longest segment of the string where 2 is not encountered.

Python is my first "scripting" language and I am still learning to successfully incorporate the built-in functionality that the language has. I have written a solution to the above problem that involves splitting the string of digits into an array of individual digits and then iterating through each and every one to find segments of digits without n. I then compare the segments to find the longest. However, the TA for this course told us there was a more "pythonic" way to approach this problem and that my current function, while working, could be significantly shorter.

I'm stumped, does anyone have a more "pythonic" solution they can assist me with? Thanks in advance!

PS: Not sure if it is relevant to a python solution, but I should mention that the string of digits can be very long in some test cases (~1000+ at times IIRC).

Comment: Strings are iterable in much the same fashion that lists are so not sure why you'd need to split the string up.

Comment: What if there are more than one segments that tie as the longest? Return all or any of them?

Comment: I assume that you want to try to figure this out yourself, so as a hint, look at the [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) function.

Comment: For this problem, there will not be any test cases that have ties for longest segments. I was actually unaware that strings were iterable in that sense. I'll make the appropriate changes in my program. And thanks, I will look at the split function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [15]: text = '1211211121'

In [16]: text.split('2')
Out[16]: ['1', '11', '111', '1']

In [18]: max(text.split('2'), key=len)
Out[18]: '111'
```

References:

- [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)

Comment: I was able to use the split command after mhawke pointed me in the right direction but I was still taking the "long" way to find the longest split. I feel silly for not thinking of using the max function since I literally wrote another function that uses it just a few days ago. Thanks for the help!